# Static resources location mapped dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently serve my static content for my webapp using Spring MVC's 'mvc:resources ...' tag, setting the URL mapping and resource location in my servlet context like so:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This works nicely, but what I'd like to do is be able to is set the "location" to a filesystem path that's dynamically configured in the application (stored in the database).  Is this possible?  (I think this would need to happen after the spring context is initialized, so I can grab the result from a service call, but I can't seem to come up with a way to make it work.)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't think it will let you take file system relative paths, only paths relative to the application context, for security reasons. This `<resources>` tag is for css, js, icons, ie. web app resources.

Comment: Thanks, Sotirios.  If I'm reading the docs correctly, it seems like you can specify a location outside the application root, if you use a 'file:/' prefix.  The problem here is that I don't know that path ahead of time, and would like to be able to set it dynamically...

Comment: Use programmatic configuration extending this class: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Bootstrap extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String path = "file:" + ...;  // 'file:/' or 'file:' depending on how your path is formatted
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(path);
    }

}
```

How you get the `path` is a different story. Maybe use an `@Autowired` or `@Bean` datasource to get a connection and query your database for the path.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to execute AFTER application context initialization (ie. if the resource location were to change at runtime)?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess a better way to phrase that question is whether I can inject the ResourceHandlerRegistry into a bean that I use at runtime...?

Comment: @BillMarkmann I don't know that you can, might be a hack to do that. This is done when your servlet container is initializing your app. What do you mean by runtime? In your configuration class you can have other `@Bean`s. You can use those inside this method.

Comment: Thanks -- let me try this out; if it works I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: @BillMarkmann This answer assumes you know about [Spring's java configuration alternative](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks, I got that working.  It seems like you can't update the ResourceHandlers after application initialization, but that's not a show stopper for my use case (I was trying to be a bit too tricky for my own good).  Anyone who comes across this later, the only thing I needed to do to get the above working was to add cglib and asm to my Maven POM.